# Make Cocoa Application Unquittable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am writing a Cocoa application that needs to NOT have the option to quit in the dock. I was able to take the menu option out application from the menu-bar. I want to take the quit option out of the dock right-click option. How would I go about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why bother?  You can't stop the user from quitting the app if they want to by using force quit.

Comment: The only use case i can even think of for this is if its an app that needs to monitor something like antivirus or a key logger or something. But if thats the case the functionality that needs to "unquitable" should really be runnig as some kind of background service, and then there should be a separate app or pref pain to control settings or perform other tasks that impact the service.

Comment: Trying to make it as hard as possible for the user to quit, the users who are using it will primarily not know how to Force Quit an application but may stumble across the right-click dock option. It isn't that important but would make it that much more easy to keep open.

Comment: But again that brings us back to the question - "Why do you not want users to quit the application?".

Comment: If your app is destined to be released via the official app store, Apple will reject it even if you do find a way, as this would be against their guidelines. If it's a legit app for a "front of shop" for example, some special cases exist that cover the home button to prevent users from exiting the app.

Comment: It isn't going to be released through the App Store, it is an in-house application that is going to be used by employees. I don't want users to be able to quit the app because it is a controller program and needs to be open to control things in the room it is placed in.

Comment: I think this is a legitimate question and I don't think it really deserves to be down-voted, even if the solution to the problem is not what the OP supposes it should be.

Answer (score 5):

You could make the app a background-only app by adding the `LSUIElement` key to your `Info.plist` file and setting its value to `YES`.

This will prevent your app from appearing in the dock and will also prevent it having a menu bar. You can present a UI to open app configuration windows etc via an `NSStatusItem` in the menu bar.

However, if this is going to be the sole app running on the system then you should make it a full-screen kiosk app, which will allow you to completely control what users can do with the system, including preventing the quitting of the app. You can read more about kiosk mode [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks this was perfect, I knew there was a way to do it. And thank you for taking the question seriously.